# Custom Dialog with align Left and Top margin in android

Tags: margin, android-dialog

I want to create custom dialog with Left and Top margins.

I tried like this

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Home.this);

dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().gravity = Gravity.LEFT|Gravity.TOP;

dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.R.color.transparent));
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.home_menu);

dialog.show();
```

It is align Left and top to the layout.It is fine but i need margins or padding's to them.If any body know about this please give me advice how i can achieve this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();

        window.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP);
        dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().verticalMargin=0.01F;
        dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().horizontalMargin=0.01F;
        wlp.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
        window.setAttributes(wlp);
        dialog.show();
```